# Using Adasyn() or SMOTE() error : Could not convert string to float

Tags: stringtokenizer

I am trying to apply SMOTE or ADASYN technique for ALECD dataframe which contains two columns of interest (event_type and notes), event type represents the event category which I factorized to integers (0-9) and notes is a free text column which describe the events , I have imbalanced numbers of events and I am trying to apply SMOTE or ADASYN to resolve the imbalance , the pre-processing goes as follows :

```
with open('2008-01-01-2018-01-01.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    ALECD = pd.read_csv(csvfile, low_memory=False)
    print(ALECD.shape)


#Cleaning data ,deleting entries with missing notes and converting event types to number
ALECD = ALECD[pd.notnull(ALECD['notes'])]
print(ALECD.shape)
ALECD['category_id'] = ALECD['event_type'].factorize()[0]
category_id_ALECD = ALECD[['event_type', 'category_id']].drop_duplicates().sort_values('category_id')
category_to_id = dict(category_id_ALECD.values)
id_to_category = dict(category_id_ALECD[['category_id', 'event_type']].values)
```

## Text Representation

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=5, norm='l2', encoding='latin-1', ngram_range=(1, 2), stop_words='english')
features = tfidf.fit_transform(ALECD.notes).toarray()
labels = ALECD.category_id
print(features.shape)
```

## splitting the data set into training and testing set

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np.array(list(ALECD['notes'])).reshape(-1, 1), \
                                                    np.array(list(ALECD['event_type'])).reshape(-1 , 1), random_state=0)
```

## Apply the random over-sampling

```
ada = ADASYN()
X_resampled, y_resampled = ada.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)
```

## Error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Pro-Houthi Saba news reported that coalition warplanes launched two air raids on Hodeidah airport on Friday, reportedly causing heavy damage. No fatalities or injuries were reported.'
```

Comment: You convert text to numerical features but you don't use it, i.e. you don't use the *features* array. Instead you use ALECD dataframe which has strings as values. ALECD is not modified in place when you apply the tfidf transformation.

Comment: Thank Georgios for the thought, but how can I make the change in array since inplace argument is not a valid parameter for np.array, can you share with me your potential solution

Comment: I used features and category_id in splitting the dataset into training and testing sets, now I have another error when trying to fit using the following code : #Vactorize the notes column of the training set
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_resampled)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)          AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: I think should be posted as a different problem now in a separate thread

Comment: The error message is clear. It tries to apply a string method to an array. On the other hand since you apply consecutive transformations check the Pipeline class of scikit-learn (or the Pipeline class of imbalanced-learn which is compatible to sampling methods).